# Checkbox background image not changing second time

Tags: jquery

I'm using an image for checkbox. When the attribute of the checkbox is changed manually through jquery the background image of the checkbox doesn't seem to change.

In this case when you click on the button 2nd time the checked image doesn't appear.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aLAgV/1/

Code

```
var $elm = $('#checkbox-1');
$('#butn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($elm.is(':checked'))
        $elm.removeAttr('checked');
    else
        $elm.attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Comment: removeattr is removing that attribute....also, should be using prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/DVuMB/

<kbd>[Prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $elm = $('#checkbox-1');
    $('#butn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $elm.prop('checked',!$elm.is(':checked'));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use checked true/false should work

```
$elm.attr('checked',true);
$elm.attr('checked',false);
```